# Getting "TypeError: res.status is not a function."

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

TypeError: res.status is not a function
at auth (D:\PROJECT\Web Application\Learning React\MERN STACK\middleware\auth.js:17:9).
I am getting this error. The code is given below.

```
const config = require("config");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

function auth(res, req, next) {
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  // Check for token
  if (!token) res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });

  try {
    // verify token
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"));
    // Add user from payload
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  }
}

module.exports = auth;
```

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3eQv.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `req, res, next`

Change

```
function auth(res, req, next) {
```

to

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
```

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html